# Sumar enteros de un array en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, array, matrices, operador

Esta es una pregunta simple pero no he encontrado ningún post relacionado con este tema.

```
matriz=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6][7,8,9]]
```

Me gustaría sumar todos los grids de esta matriz entre sí (1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9)
de forma que me devolviese 45 en una nueva variable. (¿Algo con dos ciclos for, uno dentro de otro?)

Se podría hacer también esto?:

```
var_1=1
var_2=1+2
var_3=1+2+3
var_4=1+2+3+4
var_5=...
```

Así sucesivamente con todos los grids de la matriz, un saludo, gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar dos `for` anidados, el primero que itere sobre las filas y el segundo sobre los elementos de cada fila y usar una variable para ir almacenando la suma como comentas:

```
suma = 0
for fila in matriz:
    for n in fila:
        suma += n
```

No obstante  usar el built-in `sum` es más eficiente, para poder aplicarlo una posibilidad es aplanar primero la lista y luego aplicar `sum`. Además de las formas que muestra @Ale en su respuesta podemos usar `itertools.chain.from_iterable`

```
>>> import itertools
>>> matriz = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> sum(itertools.chain.from_iterable(matriz))
45
```

Lo segundo que planteas no es más que una suma acumulada, para ello `itertools` también tiene la solución, `itertools.accumulate`:

```
>>> cumsum = list(itertools.accumulate(itertools.chain.from_iterable(matriz)))
>>> cumsum
[1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45]
```

Lo normal es usar una lista o otro iterable para almacenar las sumas acumuladas, pero si quieres usar 9 variables simplemente desempaqueta:

```
>>> cumsum = itertools.accumulate(itertools.chain.from_iterable(matriz))
>>> var_1, var_2, var_3, var_4, var_5, var_6, var_7, var_8, var_9 = cumsum
```

Answer (score 2):

Puede usar `sum()` con una expresión de generador aquí:

```
>>> matriz=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
>>> suma = sum(sum(x) for x in matriz)
>>> print(suma)
>>> 45
```

o también de la siguiente manera

```
>>> matriz=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
>>> suma = sum(sum(matriz, []))
>>> print(suma)
>>> 45
```